# Trying to deploy IBM Watson NLC in Bluemix and get Error: EACCES, mkdir '/opt/IBM/node/share/man/man3' error (every time)

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I have created the IBM Watson Natural Language Processor service and I'm trying to deploy the training application.  It creates the project, clones the repository, and configures the pipeline, but gets an error during the 'Deploy to Bluemix' step.

The error is:

```
Cloning the 'master' branch from repo 'https://P90MSG01:3041/git/esilky/ibmwatson-nlc-groundtruth-esilky-952'
/opt/IBM/node/bin/npm -> /opt/IBM/node/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, mkdir '/opt/IBM/node/share/man/man3'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, mkdir '/opt/IBM/node/share/man/man3']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/opt/IBM/node/share/man/man3' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-52-generic
npm ERR! command "/opt/IBM/node/bin/node" "/opt/IBM/node/bin/npm" "install" "npm@2.14.4" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pipeline/6abb55b0-7254-4bc1-8d74-aa4550db9b1b
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path /opt/IBM/node/share/man/man3
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, mkdir '/opt/IBM/node/share/man/man3'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pipeline/6abb55b0-7254-4bc1-8d74-aa4550db9b1b/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Finished: ERRORED
```

What needs to be done to resolve this?

Comment: Silky, you are trying to write to a directory you do not have write access to (`/opt`). The solution is stated in there: "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator".

Comment: Thank you Bill, but I'm not sure how to do that.  The Watson NLC Toolkit has a button that says:
When you click the Deploy to Bluemix button, the following steps take place:

    You are prompted to log in to Bluemix or to create an account.
    A Bluemix DevOps Services project is created, and a Git repository is initialized.
    The ibmwatson-nlc-groundtruth project is cloned into the Git repository.
    Your copy of the application is built.
    The Cloudant NoSQL DB service and Natural Language Classifier Bluemix services are created.
    The toolkit application is deployed to Bluemix.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your question was already answered [here](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/242381/i-cant-deploy-the-nlc-toolkit-beta.html).

> According to Patrick Wagstrom, the problem was fixed in December 7, 2015

If you try to deploy the NLC toolkit today it will work.
NLC Toolkit: https://hub.jazz.net/project/wdctools/ibmwatson-nlc-groundtruth/overview

Comment: I just tried again and I still get a 'failed to deploy' message.  Here is the end of the log:
> node-sass@3.3.3 postinstall /home/pipeline/0295fcf4-1990-408b-bf75-5b8a34dae30c/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

` /home/pipeline/0295fcf4-1990-408b-bf75-5b8a34dae30c/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-11/binding.node ` exists. 
 testing binary.
Binary is fine; exiting.
npm ERR! cb() never called!
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Finished: FAILED